# How to export animated character from Blender 2.8 as fbx to Unity?

Tags: animation, export, unity, .fbx, inverse-kinematics

I have a fully rigged and animated character with shape keys. I created it in 2.79, exported it using ASCII with the settings below and could use it in Unity without any problems.

[image]

However, after opening it in 2.8 and trying to export it, I realized that ASCII is no longer an option. I looked up tutorials on the binary export settings, but whatever I do the animations look weird in Unity. To be precise, the arm is deformed at the elbow (I have an IK setup and use baked animations).

I also find animations attached to the body when opening the character in Unity. These do not actually work (the character doesn't move) but I have no idea why are they there to begin with.

What export settings should I use in 2.8 to avoid these deformations? Or do I need to modify something on my model to be able to successfully export it from 2.8?

Comment: Does the IK bone have "Target" or "Pole Target"?

Comment: Yes, it has an elbow pole target.

Comment: The problem is the actions don't include contrains. If you disable the "All Action" and the "NLA Tracks" options in the exporter's animation tab probably the correct animation will be exported, but unfortunatelly you can export only one animation into one fbx file.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I thought that baking the animation means that it contains the constraints. Right now I have five animations. If I understand well, then I need to export five separated fbx files and import them all in unity to have access to all of the animations. But how can I choose which animation I want to export?
If there is really no easier method, then I guess I will be stuck with 2.79 since ASCII export is really quick and easy compared to that.

Comment: You will export what you see, so what you choose in the action editor. You can also put the animations in a raw in the NLA editor and export them as one animation and cut it into pieces in Unity.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried putting a baked animation into the action editor and export with "All Action" and "NLA Tracks" disabled, but in Unity I got no animation attached to the character. I tried tweaking the other export settings, but without luck. How should I set the other export settings in binary?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. But 2.79 worked pretty well so you can use that, or may be there is an addon or you can also import the blend file into Unity. Or you can use an fbx converter like Autodesk's fbx converter. https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-converter-archives Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I'm currently using 2.79 for rigged models, but it would be great if I could eventually use 2.8.